# draw signal spectrum using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following signal and I want to do the following:

```py
s= 4*np.cos(4*np.pi*pow(10,6)*t+30)+2*np.sin(8*np.pi*pow(10,6)*t+15)+np.cos(12*np.pi*pow(10,6)*t)+0.5*np.cos(16*np.pi*pow(10,6)*t) # the signal
```

I want to draw signal spectrum using matplotlib and numpy,
the find its bandwidth and determine if it's periodic or not

I use this code available here(https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/spectrum_demo.html)

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I now what you want to do but it seems plotting and returning all the turning points of your function should help you a lot with your problem.

Therefore you may try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

def func(t):

    # messures the time in units of
    # pow(10,6)*t

    exp = 4*np.cos(4*np.pi*t+30)+\
    2*np.sin(8*np.pi*t+15)+\
    np.cos(12*np.pi*t)+\
    0.5*np.cos(16*np.pi*t) 

    return exp



max_time = 2
time_steps = 400

# defining the signal
X = np.linspace(0,max_time,time_steps)
Y = func(X)

# getting all the max and min values
minimas = argrelextrema(Y, np.less)
maximas = argrelextrema(Y, np.greater)

# plot the singal
plt.plot(X,Y)

# plot minimas and maximas
plt.scatter(X[minimas],Y[minimas],color='r')
plt.scatter(X[maximas],Y[maximas],color='g')

plt.xlabel('t*10**6')
plt.ylabel('signal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, it seems that signal is periodic but when I draw the previous code it seems not,

Comment: That function is highly sensitive to over sampling... Just keep 'max_time=10' and change 'time_steps' from '100' to '200'. There is nothing I can further tell you that seems to be the nature of the expression. Can you tell me what this function should represent maybe the error is in there?

Comment: the should represent a signal works in Network cable and I want to draw its signal spectrum.

Comment: Yeah that explains the very high frequency's. Maybe just get rid of the ```pow(10,6)``` and measure the times in a more intuitive unit ```t_tilde = pow(10,6)*t```. Then plotting the function in the interval ```[0,10]``` is more reasonable.